# How to get url of navigated page 2 after button click of page 1 using WebBrowser Control in C#

Tags: c#

I'm successfully navigating from www.url**1**.com to www.url**2**.com using webbrowser control but iam unable to get the url of navigated page i.e., www.url**2**.com, using Webbrowser control in asp.net web application.

```
 Example:
I navigated to www.google.com

webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

in that page i programatically given some text and click google search button as follow

HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
textElement.SetAttribute("value", "your text to search");
HtmlElement btnElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")[0];
btnElement.InvokeMember("click");
```

After it navigated to 
    **[https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=dFMuWdWCHory8Afuwqog#q=your+text+to+search"]**

```
Here my Question is How to get the that particular navigated url USING WEBBROWSER CONTROL IN c# i.e.,
**https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=dFMuWdWCHory8Afuwqog#q=your+text+to+search"**
```

If you have any solution regarding this issue please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Url via Navigated event:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It helps only in windows application.. Coming to web application it won't help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `href` to link  the page since it is a web application

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google </a>
```